# Stuck in a Virtual Dungeon

Tags: cipher, visual, steganography

[image]

You're stuck in a virtual room. You tried to open the door but it seems to be locked. The robot guard opens the door's tiny window and looks at you.

> **You:** Can you please help me get out of here?  
>   The robot doesn't seem to be able to talk but he displays a message: 24D024CC246024DD24D324CD24BE= .
>
> You question yourself what does that mean and the robot goes away. You're now able to see something blurry as you look through the door's window but you can't really see it.
>
> You sit down wondering about the message and you notice something strange about the door and you also notice a bloody message craved in the wall "vRyZ2IZ".

The robot will open the door as soon as you shout the secret password. What is it?

**Hint 1:**

> The bloody message and what you can find in the image are connected.

**Hint 2:**

> The color of the message on the wall is important.

//

> Credits to PixelDungeon for the Door picture used as base for the puzzle.

Comment: It's "password"

Comment: You should try "guest"

Comment: None of them worked. :(

Comment: Can it be assumed that the tag "visual" is not decorative only? i.e. that the image is an *essential* part of the puzzle?

Comment: The tag visual is not decorative only, it is essential to solve.

Comment: Is the [tag:computer] tag appropriate?

Comment: There is indeed something strange about the door but I can't tell much more about it for now.
@EngineerToast Toast How does the computer tag work? Sorry, I'm quite new around here.

Comment: @EngineerToast if you mean [tag:computer-puzzle], I think you're correct.  [tag:visual] is accurate, but I think you need more detail than just your eyes.

Comment: @All -- for anyone who has not had time to do at least a surface examination of the door, there are some funny pixels at the bottom. They have hex-code colours 3a2f12, 532f12, 602f12, 3c2f12 and 552f12, and the surrounding colour is 4c2f12. I don't see anything else unusual, but that sure isn't to say there isn't anything.

Comment: Well, "vRyZ2IZ" doesn't appear to be an imgur link like so many of these are, at least...

Comment: The = at the end makes me think it's base64, but it's not.

Comment: @Joe Z. You should take a look at the bottom answers.

Comment: @JoeZ. -- Other encodings also use an = at the end to represent how much data was conveyed in the last byte/s. Base32 also doesn't work per Moose's answer, but I could imagine the robot is using either a non-standard encoding or not using Unicode... As a point of interest, we only see 9 (0,2,3,4,6,B,C,D,E) unique codepoints in the robot's message. It could possibly be base9 encoded? Unfortunately I don't understand the math well enough to pursue that :<

Comment: Hint added, good luck.

Comment: Do questions like these eventually get solved? I look back every so often in the hopes to sate my curiosity.

Comment: @Tikeb Even after offering bounty, there is noone updating the answer :(

Comment: I've looked at this problem quite a few times, and more since the bounty.  I'm just not sure what detail I'm missing. @justhalf

Comment: @LeppyR64 The top answer seems close, but still hasn't make use of the image. So combining these two will be the last step.

Answer (score 8):

the robots hex message decodes as the follwing text if taken as UTF16BE

> ⓐⓌ①ⓝⓓⓍⒾ

that converted to ASCII and combined with the wall-scrawl gives

> aW1ndXIvRyZ2IZ

this decodes as base64 to give ascii

> imgur/G&v!

which seems to be incomplete.

Comment: You're almost right in that part, almost, but that's not the full solution though. (:

Comment: The image name sjf2r + vRyZ2IZ decodes to 7rgb - Thought it might be the name of another image file but wasn't :(

Comment: @Tikeb You're not on the right track :p

Answer (score 6):

That´s what i think

> I think they are Unicode Code Points ... After I translate the message (16 bits at a time) I got
>  ⓐⓌ①ⓝⓓⓍⒾ (aW1ndXI) 
>  Which looks like the text carved in the wall (vRyZ2IZ)...

Comment: Can you clarify how you got that text?  e.g. treating the numbers as hex gives a bunch of `$`'s (the "24" pairs) but most of the others are unprintable in most common encodings.  What encoding were you using?

Comment: I got the same thing; if you assume the message is 64-bit Unicode, you come up with the letters in the answer, but actually all inside circles. This is noteworthy in that this answer has the same number of letters as were scratched into the wall. But, since it doesn't take information from the picture into account, I don't think it's correct.

Comment: So you're saying each 16 hex bits (`24D0`, `24CC`, etc) represents a Unicode codepoint (which are max 32 bits)?  That's the "enclosed letters" page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/2000-2FFF.  Seems like a concrete lead.

Comment: @MarkPeters -- Oops. Yes. No wonder I had so much trouble trying to find a 64-bit Unicode table... Those are the ones; as you say, if you take each 16 bits and plug them into that table, you end up with the enclosed letters which are given in the answer.

Comment: Good job @Vinicius de Castro but unfortunately that's not yet the solution.

Comment: @MarkPeters Dammit, so _that_ was the pattern D:

Comment: @JoeZ. Good job so far but that's not yet the solution. :>

Comment: Adding up to Joe Z. answer, note that the image is 160x160 pixels. Joe Z. said the following: "I think they are Unicode Code Points ... After I translate the message (16 bits >! at a time). So the image is like, 16*10 x 16*10" Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

I posted this as a comment yesterday, but it occurs to me I should post it as a full answer, buried as it is in the comments.

> For those who have not zoomed in to have a look, there is something odd at the bottom of the door. Specifically, five pixels that do not belong. They have hex colours 3a2f12, 532f12, 602f12, 3c2f12 and 552f12. The surrounding colour is 4c2f12

For the curious:

> [image]
>  Depending on how your browser renders images, it may appear very blurry. If that is the case, [download it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fYRE.png) and open it with a real image editor, e.g. GIMP, then zoom in.

To decode this information, I have tried:

> Notice that the hex colours all have the same last four hexdigits. If one takes the first two and naïvely decodes them into UTF-8, one gets the string:
> :S`<UL
> Which I can't make any sense of.

Comment: That's a good start though. I've added a tiny hint on the main post. Good luck!

Comment: those pixels you found are the only pixels in the image not in consistent 10x10 blocks.

Comment: @Jasen - they are the only ones I saw, anyway

Comment: I did a search, there are no others.

Comment: Ahhh the colour on the wall is 7rgb

Comment: how is 7rgb a colour?

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought it was

> Base-64 encoded, but when I decoded, I would get "ۀۀێۀۀۀۀD" which is definitely not right.

Then I noticed,

> The door looks like something out of Minecraft, which made me wonder if it could be Base-32 encoded, so when I decoded that, I got "not a UTF-8 string", so that's obviously incorrect. However, the message appears to be in hexadecimal form

Comment: I guess that sometimes things can't always be so straightforward.

Comment: Nope :P I'm gonna take a little break and let some other people take a look

Comment: the door is from *Pixel Dungeon*, that is stated in the question.

Comment: @Jasen - That the door is from Pixel Dungeon was only added a day or two after this question was published, and this answer was first added a few minutes after it was published :)

Comment: @Sompom That's not true :p The door was always there, I just made a quick fix on it on the same day I posted, as far as I remember. o:

Comment: @andré - The door was always there, but we didn't know where it came from until I did a reverse-image search using it and found that it came from Pixel Dungeon, after which I suggested you mention that was the source in the original question. Before that, Moose and I didn't know where it came from :)

Comment: @Sompom Oh, I understand now. Yes, that's true.

Comment: Oh yeah I haven't looked at this in a few days